# Importar dados de arquivo xlsx para SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá,
Estou criando uma SP para realizar exportação de dados de uma planinha no formato xlsx (Excel ), entretanto não estou obtendo sucesso. 
O meu SQL SERVER é uma versão antiga SQL Server 2000 (Build Version 8.00.2187), e não sou administrador.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [citdifo].[spImportaTempoDeAnalise] 
    @caminhoArquivo VARCHAR(300)
AS
DECLARE @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise VARCHAR(100), @consultaSQL VARCHAR(5000)

PRINT @caminhoArquivo
SET @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise = 'tbTmpTempoDeAnalise' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@SPID)
PRINT @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise
IF OBJECT_ID(@tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise) IS NULL BEGIN

    SET @consultaSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' +  @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise + ' (
    Matrícula VARCHAR(70)  NULL,
    Conta VARCHAR(70)  NULL,
    Tipo VARCHAR(70)  NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(15)  NULL,
    Horário VARCHAR(50)  NULL
    )'
    PRINT 'AQUI1'

END ELSE BEGIN

    SET @consultaSQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise
    PRINT 'AQUI2'

END
PRINT @consultaSQL
EXEC(@consultaSQL)

SET @consultaSQL = 'BULK INSERT ' + @tabelaTmpTempoDeAnalise + ' FROM ''' + @caminhoArquivo + ''' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', FORMAT=''xlsx'')'
--SET consultaSQL = SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0', 'EXCEL 13.0;Database=C:\Tempo de Análise - C024880 - 01-02-2019.xlsx ', [Data$]);
PRINT @consultaSQL
EXEC(@consultaSQL)`
```

O erro apresentado quando executo a SP é:

```
BULK INSERT tbTmpTempoDeAnalise59 FROM 'C:\Users\c108949\Downloads\qualidade\Tempo de Análise - C024880 - 01-02-2019.xlsx' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FORMAT='xlsx')
```

Mensagem 170, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 3
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.
Já tentei sem passar o parâmetro Format e não obtive sucesso.

Li alguns procedimentos que poderiam dar certo, entretanto ainda não estou obtendo sucesso. 
Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e poderia me orientar.
Obrigado.

Comment: Exporte um CSV do Excel para facilitar a vida.

Comment: FORMAT não existe na versão SQL Server em uso e arquivos XLSX necessitam do Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Também sugiro que, **(1)** no Excel, exporte os dados da planilha como arquivo CSV e **(2)** no SQL Server importe os dados do arquivo CSV para a tabela.